# Why parameter for lambda function is passed like this?

Tags: python, lambda

```
people = ['Dr. Christopher Brooks', 'Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson', 'Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran', 'Dr. Daniel Romero']

def split_title_and_name(person):
    return person.split()[0] + ' ' + person.split()[-1]

#option 1
for person in people:
    print(split_title_and_name(person) == (lambda x: x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1])(person))
```

When and where to use the above lambda parameter. Since the lambda parameter used above is x but after lambda function, person list is passed inside a parenthesis, which substitutes x.

For the above code, I get 4 True due to 4 items in the list.

```
#option 1
for person in people:
    print(split_title_and_name(person) == (lambda person: person.split()[0] + ' ' + person.split()[-1]))
```

But this code doesn't show the same result. It gives 4 False

Comment: In your second code, you are creating lambdas and *not calling them* - you are comparing strings and functions, that cannot ever be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(lambda x: x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1])(person)` is equivalent to the following code:

```
def any_name(x):
    return x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1]

any_name(person)
```

As you can see, `lambda` creates an anonymous function that is called at once and discarded; `x` is the formal parameter and `person` is the actual parameter. The name of the formal parameter in a function definition does not matter; it could as well be `person`.